# What is the best way to achieve sscanf-like functionality in Perl?

Tags: c, regex, perl, string

What is the best way to achieve `sscanf`-like functionality in Perl?

I am looking at the `sscanf` module.

Which is better:

1. Going `sscanf` way?
2. Regex way? (I am a beginner when it comes to Regex.)

Comment: Give us samples of your data so we can supply helpful advice that's specific to your situation. The answer, however, is almost certainly to use regular expressions or perhaps a bona fide parser.

Comment: Do you mean the [String::Sscanf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3A%3AScanf) module? [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX) says it doesn't implement `sscanf`.

Answer (score 10):

The Perl documentation includes this tidbit:

> - [**scanf**](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#scanf)
>
>   scanf() is C-specific, use <> and regular expressions instead, see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

I would say that learning regexes is well worth it; they are part of the core strength of Perl and are a useful tool elsewhere too.

Comment: Note the output of `perl -MPOSIX -e 'scanf'`

Answer (score 6):

[CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) has a [String::Sscanf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3A%3AScanf) module for Perl!

Regex is better, but TIMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do it<sup>TM</sup>.

However, regular expressions are quite more versatile than sscanf.  They are also not difficult to learn.

In Perl, an attempt to mimic the functionality of sscanf would most likely make heavy use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression.

If you want to use the sscanf module, you need to download that module. So it will occupies the space.

Instead of this, you use the regular expression only.

According to me regular expression is the better way